# Change a <div> width without affecting content with margin:auto

Tags: html, css

I have been wrestling with this issue for a while and couldn't find a similar question:

I am trying to change the width of a `<div>` without affecting its content, meaning I don't want the content to move or readjust in anyway. At the same time, I need the content to be centered in the page depending on the screen resolution.

Everything works fine when I don't use `margin:0 auto;` in my CSS, but that is not the result I want since the content is not centered anymore.

I am still learning CSS and if anyone could take a look at the Code Pen I created I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

========EDIT=========

Please look at the codepen, this is what I am trying to achieve:
When the width of the `<div>` is changed, the text should not change position or be readjusted in anyway. 
This can be achieved by deleting `margin:0 auto;` from the CSS section: The text does not change position and it's cut short when the `<div>` width is changed.

But I need `margin:0 auto;` to stay to make sure that the `<div>` content adapts to screen resolution.

Hope this clarifies intent.

[Code Pen Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNLajP)

Comment: What do you expect it to happen when that width changed?

Comment: I want the text to not change position. But the margins are changed when the width of the <div> changes. I want the margin to change only depending on screen size

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for, you can fix this by CSS flex property instead of position "absolute"

[Try this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtuh95ac/)

```
.wrapper-cme {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but this is not what I am looking for. The text in your fiddle is now readjusting altogether. I don't want the text to move at all, when the <div> width is changed its content should be cut short, not readjusted in any way. I will clarify my intent in the question.